# Errors linking to Boost system

Tags: c++, boost, linker, mingw

I've built Boost 1.59 for MinGW 4.9.2 32bit as follows:

1. `bootstrap.bat mingw`
2. `b2 --prefix=%USERPROFILE%\Code\Libraries\boost toolset=gcc install` (these are static libraries)

When trying to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t.wait();
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With:

```
g++ -o test -L %USERPROFILE%\Code\Libraries\boost\lib -l boost_system-mgw49-mt-1_59 -I %USERPROFILE%\Code\Libraries\boost\include\boost-1_59 main.cpp
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Brady\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsbGjrk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x193): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:\Users\Brady\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsbGjrk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x19d): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:\Users\Brady\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsbGjrk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
C:/Program Files (x86)/QT/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Brady\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsbGjrk.o: bad reloc address 0xe in section `.text$_ZN5boost6system14error_categoryD2Ev[__ZN5boost6system14error_categoryD2Ev]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm getting this same error across 2 computers. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a linker error. You need to link to the Boost System library.

Do this

```
g++ -o test -L %USERPROFILE%\Code\Libraries\boost\lib -lboost_system -I %USERPROFILE%\Code\Libraries\boost\include\boost-1_59 main.cpp
```

Comment: `C:/Program Files (x86)/QT/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status` This is why I used `-l boost_system-mgw49-mt-1_59`

Comment: You need to enable verbose mode to see what's going on, where linker is looking for files. The linker does give verbose output if you set -Wl,--verbose

Comment: I'm assuming `%USERPROFILE%\Code\Libraries\boost\lib` should be in the `LIBRARY_PATH`? It isn't in my case.

Comment: No you are not. -L option sets the lib path where linker will search

Comment: Did you try verbose mode

Comment: Yes that's where I noticed `boost\lib` wasn't in the `LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Remove the space between -L and lib path

Comment: The problem isn't I can't find boost_system, I can't link to it. https://gist.github.com/2bdkid/ae40a8c7ef58b88a413e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90191/discussion-between-user1-and-brady-dean).